# $Q:\mathbb{M}^{\perp}\rightarrow \mathbb{H}/\mathbb{M}$ is an isometric isomorphism

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, quotient-spaces

> Let $\mathbb{H}$ be a Hilbert space and $\mathbb{M}$ be a closed
>   subspace. Show that if
>   $Q:\mathbb{H}\rightarrow{\mathbb{H}}/{\mathbb{M}}$ is the natural map ( That is $Q(x)=x+\mathbb{M}$ ),
>   then $Q:\mathbb{M}^{\perp}\rightarrow \mathbb{H}/\mathbb{M}$ is an
>   isometric isomorphism
>   *(Functional analysis by John B Conway:Banach Spaces: Section 4)*

So what we have to prove is that $\forall x\in \mathbb{M}^{\perp}, ||Q(x)||=||x||$
And it is always true that $||Q(x)||=||x+\mathbb{M}||\leq||x||$.

So I was looking for the other direction of the inequality. And I don't see how to involve the properties of $\mathbb{M}^{\perp}$.

Alternatively I considered the inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ and tried to prove $||Q(x)||^2=\langle Q(x),Q(x)\rangle=\langle x,x\rangle=||x||^2$ but wasn't successful.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Call $\|a\|_q$  the norm in the quotient, which is defined as $\inf_{x\in a+\mathbb{M}}\|x\|$, where $\|x\|$ is the norm in $\mathbb{H}$. Then, for $a\in\mathbb{M}^{\bot}$ you have that $\|Q(a)\|_q=\inf_{x\in a+\mathbb{M}}\|x\|$. Write $x=a+b$ with $b\in\mathbb{M}$. Then $\|x\|^2=\|a+b\|^2=\|a\|^2+\|b\|^2\geq \|a\|^2$. Therefore $\|Q(a)\|_q=\inf_{x\in a+\mathbb{M}}\|x\|=\|a\|$.

Comment: Ah I see. So you are using the unique decomposition ( $\mathbb{H}=\mathbb{M}\oplus\mathbb{M}^{\perp} $). And then since the two elements are perpendicular you can use the Pythagoras' identity.. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's all.

Comment: Thank you very much!